# Please, fix the broken windows

Tags: discussion

If we let "broken windows" visible now, this site will pass the wrong message to new users and permanently will need to handling broken windows.

We must give the right tone to the site, this is the purpose of private beta phase.

Please fix *your* broken windows. Let a comment for users fix their broken windows.

Example: Fix the case on questions, specially on titles. provide proper tags

High scored users reaching the edit rights could help us either.

Comment: what does "broken-windows" mean?

Comment: [Broken Window](http://tinyurl.com/bae97v): *"It’s pretty clear now that the broken windows theory applies to community sites as well. The theory is that minor forms of bad behavior encourage worse ones: that a neighborhood with lots of graffiti and broken windows becomes one where robberies occur. I was living in New York when Giuliani introduced the reforms that made the broken windows theory famous, and the transformation was miraculous. And I was a Reddit user when the opposite happened there, and the transformation was equally dramatic."*

Comment: P. Graham and lisp rock!

Answer (score 2):

Help me see if I understand you:

a) we need to have the *right* sort of questions on this site.

b) we need to have questions that "don't make you cringe when you see them"

---

How do we do this? What if I think a question is not right for this site? Do I VtC it or do I only leave a comment or ... Where do we draw the line? Do I go ahead and say "this belongs on SO"? Who else will join in on that battlecry?

Actually, I'm going to post a new meta.DBA question on this.